# double noun possessives

Tags: grammar

I'm writing a poem referring to humans as landlords of this planet.

Which is correct:

"they come to test this planet landlord's heart"

or

"they come to test this planet's landlord's heart"

I would use the first one for what I consider better style. Not sure it is correct.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm writing a poem referring to humans as landlords of this planet.
>
> Which is correct:
>
> "they come to test this planet landlord's heart"
>
> or
>
> "they come to test this planet's landlord's heart"

**Answer:** None of the above.

Humans are plural so the correct version is:

*"They come to test this planet's landlords' heart."*  [Note position of the second apostrophe.]

or, if you think hearts should be plural:

*"They come to test this planet's landlords' hearts."*

Answer (score 1):

*"they come to test this planet landlord's heart"*

This implies there are other *planet landlords* (whose hearts may or may not be tested).

*"they come to test this planet's landlord's heart"*

More scientific; we are dealing only with this planet and this planet's landlord.

Comment: If we accept the notion this planet (earth) has a landlord (the human species), it would seem to follow that that there are indeed other planet landlords throughout the universe--and of course the assumption that life exists on other planets is becoming harder to resist. However, the distinction Dan is making is lost of me: if "we are dealing only with this planet and this planet's landlord," the implication still exists that "there are other planet landlords (whose hearts may or may not be tested)."

Comment: Let me try and explain ...  I understand *planet landlord* as a kind of title -  *Planet-Landlord*.  So when I hear *this planet landlord's heart...* it makes me wonder too about the heart's of other planet-landlords.  Although this  CAN be understood from *this planet's landlord*, actually, for me, this version makes me wonder only about other attributes of *this* planet - this planet's guardians, this planet's enemies ... (i.e. my mind does not move so automatically into considering other planets).  I guess it depends upon whether the OP wants extra-terrestrial resonance.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason not to use the first if you prefer it, for style or rhythm. "Planet" in this case works as an adjective (as in "Tenement landlords take advantage of the zoning laws.")

Comment: Except that the use of nouns as attributives is not totally productive, and I've never heard of _planet landlords_.  Mind you, the alternative isn't all that attractive either.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the answers.

I've changed the sentence to:
"They come to point earth’s landlords’ souls for voiceless  pleas"

But I'm still not sure about so many "s" for style. Difficult to read out load.